# How can I quickly identify the path and the search pattern in C:\Users\Admin\Samples\*.pdf?

Tags: c#, .net, command-line, io, command-line-arguments

I would like to create a simple copy console application (I know copy already exists in DOS). Exactly like the DOS copy command I would like to be able to execute my copy application with two simple arguments:

```
copy C:\Users\Admin\Samples\*.pdf C:\
```

1. Input path and search pattern
2. Ouput path

In my code I use this

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    string input;
    string output;

    var options = new Options();
    ICommandLineParser parser = new CommandLineParser();
    if (parser.ParseArguments(args, options))
    {
        input = options.Argument[0];
        output = options.Argument[1];

        // Get file list
        String directory = Path.GetDirectoryName(input);
        String[] files = Directory.GetFiles(directory, /* ??? */);
        // To be continued...
    }
    else
    {
        System.Console.WriteLine("Erreur");
        System.Console.ReadKey();
    }
}
```

How can I easely retrieve my search pattern? Is beter way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(input);
string inputDirectory = System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(input);
```

I think this is what you wanted.

Answer (score 0):

To get the path, or the file, of the input parameter, you can use the following:

```
Path.GetFileName(input);
```